# Declaring, defining, assigning, initialising variables

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, definition, assign

This is in reference to C++. This question I have goes back about 6 months, when I used to think that a declaration was:

```
int a;
```

And a definition was:

```
a = 5;
```

Also, that:

```
int a = 5;
```

was both a declaration and definition.

I've now come to understand that:

```
int a;
```

Is a definition, not just a declaration. (I don't know why).

Also, there are terms such as assigning, and initialising which add further jargon to the issue.

So here is my current understanding (and please correct anything):

```
int a;    // Declaration and definition

int a = 5 // Declaration, definition, assignation and initialisation.

a = 5;    // Initialising (if for the first time),
          // assigning (if for subsequent times),
          // defining (not sure about this one).
```

I have read quite a bit on this topic but am still confused. Can someone explain exactly what each is? I know that in such cases there are philosophical disputes, like is zero an even number, or even a number. Haha, but can someone try? Thanks.

Comment: "initialize" means that you provide an initial value  (special case is when you explicitly provide an empty list, that still counts as initialization).

Answer (score 0):

A **declaration** may introduce one or more names into a translation unit or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations.

A **definition** is a declaration in some [specific circumstance](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#2). (ie, a declaration with initializer). This is because they have to meet the One definition rule.
All definitions are declarations, but not vice-versa.

**Initialization** gives an initial value to a variable in its definition. Initialization will also happens in other situation (eg. function argument passing)

**Assignment** is used to assign a new value to an already existing object.

In your specific case

```
int a;    // definition, default-initialization if it's local, zero-initialization otherwise
int a = 5; // definition, copy-initiaization
a = 5;   // assignment
```

Also, the following is a declaration but not a definition

```
extern int i;  // declaration but not definition
```

Comment: Why this old question appears in the active questions? I'm not the one who digs it up.

Comment: I asked this ages when I was first learning. The meanings seem rather arbitrary and depend on the standard I think. For example, is an int declared in a class a definition? I don't think it is, just a declaration. But outside a class in global space it is.